# How to parameterize XML using RestAssured Java

Tags: java, xml, api, parameter-passing, rest-assured

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<videoGame category="${category}" rating="90">
   <id>${id}</id>
   <name>${name}</name>
   <releaseDate>2011-12-05T00:00:00+05:30</releaseDate>
   <reviewScore>95</reviewScore>
</videoGame>
```

I have this above XML file for which i want pass values for name, id and category every time i run my script

I am using RestAssured libraries to automate the APIs, how can i handle this using RestAssured

If not is there any other way to handle this

Comment: It seems to be like you haven't made any attempt to automate using Rest Assured

Comment: @WilfredClement i have already tried to automate using RestAssured. This is what i have tried. Copy the XML file into StringBuffer and Replace those attributes with actual data and this is feasible when i have small XML file, but when i have very big XML file how can i achieve it